# Театры, кинотеатры - в общем

Tags: грамотная-речь

Писала текст и меня заклинило: как в общем обозвать всевозможные зрелищные учреждения, типа театров, кинотеатров, цирков и т.д.? На ум приходит "учреждения культуры", но это больше ассоциируется со всевозможными министерствами.
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре театр, кинотеатр, цирк определяются как зрелищные предприятия (это их общее определение).

Сочетание "зрелищные учреждения" в словарях не применяется, например: цирк - это учреждение, зрелищное предприятие, устраивающее представления с участием акробатов, жонглёров, дрессировщиков и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Так и пишите, что **"зрелищные учреждения"**.
Некогда термин был распространен, потом как-то подзабылся.